# Android screen brightness changes not working

Tags: android, screen

i have the following code to change screen brightness when i press and hold a button

```
ImageButton mfdBRTUp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBRTup);
mfdBRTUp.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    boolean mHeldDown = false;
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {


        if (arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            mHeldDown = true;
            Thread thread = new Thread()
            {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        while(mHeldDown) {
                            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    mBackLightValue += 4;
                                    if(mBackLightValue>100)
                                        mBackLightValue=100;
                                    Log.d("onCreateOptionsMenu", "onTouch ACTION_DOWN mBackLightValue="+mBackLightValue);
                                    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
                                    layoutParams.screenBrightness = mBackLightValue;
                                    getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
                                }
                            });                                 
                            sleep(100);
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            thread.start();

        }
        if (arg1.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            mHeldDown = false;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

all seems well, the logcat output shows the mBackLightValue going up to 100 (i have another almost identical button for down of course)

the problem is, it does nothing. i check my screen brightness control in settings and its not automatic.

i've read several threads on this subject and all seem to say the only thing necessary is this

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
layoutParams.screenBrightness = mBackLightValue;
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
```

no permissions or anything extra, so what am i missing? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be driving the brightness up to 100, but screen brightness should be in the range of **0 to 1**, not **0 to 100**. Anything over 1 will be read as full brightness, which is probably the cause of your issue. Try changing your code to increase by 0.04 and max out at 1, instead of 4 and 100.

Source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#screenBrightness

Comment: ah, stupid me, i missed that. works perfect now. by the way, do you know how to read the current state of the brightness?

Comment: Give this a try: `int curBrightnessValue = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS);` That might return in the range of 0 to 100 though, if my memory serves. Still, easy enough to just divide by `100.0f` though.